# Postgres merge example using other table

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5, upsert

I am trying to perform upsert using merge operator , soon enough realised postgres does not hve same merge statement like SQL Server, and multiple posts are referring to "insert on conflict" statement instead to simulate.

I have Stage table (tabB) and Final table (tabA) - and need to upsert the records from  STAGE table into Final table TabA.

TabA

```
id   |  Val
------------
1    | 20     
3    | 30          
5    | 30
```

TabB

```
id   |  Val
------------
3    | 40          
6    | 50
```

Below statement I tried does not work, saying ambiguous reference - I could not find examples involving 2 tables ;

```
Insert into tabA( id,val)
    Select id,val
    From tabB 
    On conflict (id)
    Do update set (id, val) = (id,val)
```

Above does not work..can someone point me in right direction

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement are all more helpful than code that doesn't work.

Comment: "*Does not work*" is not a valid Postgres error message

Comment: My bad.. I added some more description now, please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, one obvious error in your code is that you are trying to update the ID column which is also used as the unique column.

The update should also reference the `excluded` record to avoid the error message about the "ambiguous"  column reference. `id` could reference the current value stored in the table or the new value provided by the insert statement.

```
insert into tabA(id, val)
select id, val
from tabB 
on conflict (id) 
do update 
  set val = excluded.val;
```